# DB design when data is unknown about an entity?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, schema

I'm wondering if the following DB schema would have repercussions later. Let's say I'm writing a place entity. I'm not certain what properties of `place` will be stored in the DB. I'm thinking of making two tables: one to hold the required (or common) info, and one to hold additional info.

**Table 1 - Place**

- PK PlaceId
- Name
- Lat
- Lng
- etc... *(all the common fields)*

**Table 2 - PlaceData**

- PK DataId
- PK FieldName
- PK FK PlaceId
- FieldData

**Usage Scenario**

I want certain visitors to have the capability of entering custom fields about a place. For example, a restaurant is a place that *may* have the following fields: HasParking, HasDriveThru, RequiresReservation, etc... but a car dealer is also a place, and those fields wouldn't make sense for a car dealer.

I want to support any type of place, from a single table (well, 2nd table has custom fields), because I don't know the number of *types* of places that will eventually be added to my site.

**Overall goal**

On my asp.net MVC (C#/Razor) site, where I display a `place`, it will show the attributes, as a unordered list populated by: `SELECT * FROM PlaceData WHERE PlaceId = @0`.

This way, I wouldn't need to show empty field names on the view (or do a `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` check for each and every field. Which I would be forced to do if every attribute was a column on the table.

I'm assuming this scenario is quite common, but are there better ways to do it? Particularly from a performance perspective? What are the major drawbacks of this schema?

Comment: Maybe so... but I don't want to build it and then learn of the glaring issues of this design. Thanks for the comment, much appreciated.

Comment: @Chad, a quick look at your schema suggests that one `person` can have `multiple`(not fixed number) `data`. If the number of `FieldData` attributes is fixed (for example, one person can only 3 fieldData) then you need to relook into the design.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to let visitors add as many attributes about each person in the database as they can, but that the attribute must be unique. For example, if someone already added a website attribute to a person, then nobody else would be able to (unless the just named it something else of course).

Comment: @Chad: And that "unless they just named it something else" is absolutely going to crush you. You've just made every casual visitor your database designer. If you provide a separate table to store multiple phone numbers for a person (for example), you'll find some users storing "phone", "phone num", "cell phone", "rufnummer", and "puhelinnumero" in PersonData anyway. Queries to return phone numbers will turn horribly complex, if they're even possible at all. Build a proper data model instead.

Comment: @Catcall: thanks for your insight. The only query I plan to do is "SELECT * FROM PersonData WHERE PersonId = @0". I did think of that nightmare scenario, after I wrote my comment. I think to combat this, I'd provide an array of choices... but something more flexible than hard coded columns.

Comment: @Chad: Arrays are less flexible than named columns. "Hard coded" isn't accurate; column names are a table's public interface. Along with the column name, you get type safety, column-level constraints, and indexes, and formal logic. And column names coincidentally follow the OOP mantra "Don't repeat yourself". Use an array, and you have to remember to use and update that array in every application that hits the database. Last Fortune 500 I worked in had programs written in at least 25 different languages hitting their operational database.

Comment: @Catcall - thanks, that's some great insight. I didn't think of it from an angle where there would be more than one app running off the db. I plan on only one app, written 100% by myself. If I do go with columns for as many types as I can think of, how many is too many?

Comment: @Chad: Each column that should actually be a table with a foreign key reference is one too many. (Like hobbies. Many people have more than one; people's hobbies should be a table, not a column.) But the *number* of columns itself--large or small--doesn't violate any relational modeling principle.

Comment: Hmm... what if Person was `Place` instead? The place could be a restaurant with certain fields (HasParking, HasDriveThru, RequiresReservation, etc..). But what if the place was a car dealer? Those same fields wouldn't match the car dealer. I'd rather not have separate tables for every type of place... as there could potentially be *lots* of types (a park, car dealer, restaurant, shopping mall, etc...) all with differing properties. What would you recommend in that scenario?

Comment: @Catcall, I updated my question to further the `place` example.

Comment: @Chad: If you don't know ahead of time whether you're going to store information about a person or a place, then a SQL database probably isn't the right tool for you. Maybe a no-sql database instead? http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: @Catcall, I've thought of it... but have absolutely no experience with a NoSQL DB. I'd pick RavenDB, since it is .Net based... but again, development would probably slow to a crawl while I learn a new tech.

Is the schema/scenario I described above really that bad?

Comment: @Chad: Yeah, it's that bad. You can't just serve up a random assortment of field names and values to your users. You have to provide web page readers (people, that is) some kind of structure. You can't display "fax number" near the top of the page, then 30 more fields, then "phone number". Nobody will use a site like that.

Comment: @Catcall, thx for your comments. What if, *most* of the info was part of the `Place` entity (Description, Lat, Lng, Name, Address, website. Then ~5-10 "custom" entries in the `PlaceData` table for properties of places that cannot be determined ahead of time (i.e. Restaurants: HasDriveThru, ReservationOnly - which would not apply to a Car Dealer, but a car dealer has it's own: HasUsed, AcceptsTradeIn...) Most of the data is in the `Place` table, but a few custom properties, displayed as a list (alphabetical order) next to the main description - not relying 100% on data in the `PlaceData` table.

Comment: @Chad: Permissions are black and white. If your users *can* create 125 virtual columns, sooner or later one of them will. (Usually sooner.) When you surrender control of part of your schema to casual users, you can't count on anything. You can't count on data to be present; you can't count on data to be absent; you can't count on data to have a sane data type; you can't count on only 5 or 10 field names. Users will do what the database allows them to do, no matter how nonsensical.

Comment: @Catcall: very true... I'd have to build some kind of protection into the business logic. I guess that's the price I'd have to pay for the flexibility I need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your **application to be able to create** its own custom fields, this is a fine model. The Mantis Bugtracker uses this as well to allow Admins to add custom fields to their tickets.

If in any case, it's going to be the **programmer that is going to create** the field, I must agree with pst that this is more a premature optimization.

Comment: Actually I do want certain visitors to have the capability of entering custom fields. For example, maybe someone knows that Bob (who is a person entity) has an interesting hobby. They'd enter a new PersonData entry (with Bob's id as the FK), set the fieldname to "Hobby" and the value to "Model ship building". (I'll add this to the question, thanks!)

Comment: Off course if you give the right to create custom fields to anyone, you'll end up with 1000 different custom fields. For displaying on a profile page, this is fine, but statistics or searching will be a lot more difficult.

Comment: Yes... I agree. Perhaps I'd provide an array of possible choices. But, something more flexible than hard coded columns.

Answer (score 6):

Your idea is referred to as an Entity-Attribute-Value table and is generally bad news in a RDBMS. RDBMSes are geared toward highly structured data.

The overall options are:

1. Model the db further in an RDBMS, which is most likely if someone is holding back specs from you.
2. Stick with the RDBMS, using XML columns for the data whose structure is variable. This makes the most sense if a relatively small portion of your data storage schema is semi- or un-structured. Speaking from a MS SQL Server perspective, this data can be indexed and you can perform checks that your data complies with an XML schema definition.
3. Move to a non-relational DB such as MongoDB, Cassandra, CouchDB, etc. This is what a lot of social sites and I suspect blog sites run with. Also, it is within reason to use a combination of RDBMS and non-relational stores if that's what your needs call for.

EAV gets to be a mess because you're creating a database within a database and lose all of the benefits a RDBMS can provide (foreign keys, data type enforcement, etc.) and the SQL code needed to reconstruct your objects goes from lasagna to fettuccine to spaghetti in the blink of an eye.

Given the information that's been added to the question, it would seem a good fit to create a PlaceDetails column of type XML in the Place table. You could also split that column into another table with a 1:1 relationship if performance requirements dictate it.

The upside to doing it that way is that you can retrieve the data using very simple SQL code, even using the xml data type's methods for searching the data. But that approach also allows you to do the more complex presentation-oriented data parsing in C#, which is better suited to that purpose than T-SQL is.

Comment: I agree... but in this case, it isn't much different than say a blog post entry with any given number of tags, correct? That's used across a great deal of blogs across the Internet.

Comment: If the users will be entering tags, drop the EAV in an RDBMS design from consideration. Your hair line will thank you. I've added to my answer to clarify what each is better for.

Comment: I'd say there's just as much structure in an EAV implementation as there is in a SQL implementation. It's just that you're letting casual users build the structure on the fly, and the structure isn't under the control of the dbms.

Comment: Think of it like component re-use. A programmer has to build app code to use an EAV design with a relational database. There are non-relational database engines that natively support the EAV design. So, you could either create your own data storage management code (reinventing the wheel) or use a tool already written for that purpose (code re-use). I know I can't write a document or key-value database on my own better than what's been done with other well-done projects, so I use their tool instead.

Comment: It just so happens that RDBMSes have evolved to support XML data, so you don't have to leave an RDBMS if only a small portion of your data is semi-structured. EAV on it's own is a useful tool. EAV + current RDBMS = horror show.

Answer (score 2):

At any given time you can add new columns to the database (always watching for the [third normalization rule](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/3nf.htm)) so you should go with what you want and only create a second table if needed or if such columns breaks any of the [normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_forms).

Comment: I've kept that in mind, but in my case I don't know the number of fields.

Comment: Then, as the rest say, don't jump ahead of requirements :).

Comment: Sry Pedro, I should have said the requirement is "I'll never know which columns, and how many, will be needed".

Comment: Then that design should be fine. I would also, perhaps, add a third table to hold metadata of the dynamically changing one.